# POWER BI visual refresh

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a dashboard in power bi with multiple tabs. If I filter data on first tab and go to second tab and then go back to first tab data refreshes and filter setting applied lost which should not. Can anyone help in this

I tried many solutions from google searches. Nothing worked